# Capturing Reverse Matches of Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that matches emoticons like :-), *<|:-), etc.

Now that I'm able to match these, I'd like to use my regex to match emoticons whose characters are written in reverse order such as (-:

It seems that lookahead, lookbehind, and lookaround assertions won't do the trick as these are non-capturing. Is there an easy way that I can reverse the regex without having to completely rewrite it in reverse order?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, one thing you could do is first reverse the string you're searching, then find the matches, then reverse the results if needed.

Comment: I doubt it can be that simple since you need to flip the `(`s, `<`s and `[`s and suchlike symbols.

Comment: Could you show us the regex?

Comment: I guess if it's a complicated procedure then I'll do what @TomKarzes suggested. I just though that maybe there was some reverse lookup option for regex.

Comment: @stribizhev Oh, yes, good point - it's not just a matter of reversing the sequence, but some of the characters need to change as well, e.g. "(" vs. ")" etc.

Comment: @TomKarzes Luckily this shouldn't be a problem for me as I have matching characters in my regex since I also have to search for emoticons such as :-(

Answer (score 0):

A better solution may be to generate a regex pattern in the language you are using, this way you don't have to manually create every emoticon backwards and forwards. For example, in ES6:

```
var emoticons = [":-)", "*<|:-)"],
    patterns = [];

var REVERSE_SWAP = {
  "(": ")",
  ")": "(",
  "]": "[",
  "[": "]",
  "<": ">",
  ">": "<"
}

for (let emoticon of emoticons) {
  patterns.push(emoticon);
  let reverse = [...emoticon].reverse();
  for (let char in reverse) {
    reverse[char] = REVERSE_SWAP[reverse[char]] || reverse[char];
  }
  patterns.push(reverse.join(""));
}

patterns = patterns.map(pattern => {
  return pattern.replace(/([\/\\\|\(\)*])/g, (match => {
    return "\\" + match;
  }));
});

var regex = new RegExp("/(" + patterns.join("|") + ")/g");
```

This will generate the following RegEx pattern:

```
/(:-\)|\(-:|\*<\|:-\)|\(-:\|>\*)/g
```

Comment: This would work if I had a small number of emoticons I was trying to match, but I'm matching something like 500 of them and I already have the regex. Thanks though.

Comment: Is there a solution for python ?